# In class initialization of constant member

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, constants

Why does the compiler (clang) complain that the `mymy` is uninitialized, when I specifically have told it to be a constant value, holding 50. And why does it allow me to change it to be 23 ... when I still have told him to be constant?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:

    Base(int y) : my(y) {std::cout << "Base:" << my << std::endl;}
private:
    int my;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base(mymy), mymy(23) {std::cout << "Derived:" << mymy << std::endl;}


private:

    const int mymy = 50;
};

int main()
{
    Derived a;
}
```

Strangely, coliru compiles without a hick. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63629c2d99bf6f43 (Yes, I know changing it to `static` will fix this problem)

Comment: Note that passing `mymy` to `Base` is undefined behaviour as it is uninitialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard says that (§12.6.2/10<sup>1</sup>, emphasis is mine):

> If a given non-static data member has both a default member initializer and a *mem-initializer*, the initialization
>   specified by the *mem-initializer* is performed, and **the non-static data member’s default member initializer is ignored**. [ *Example:* Given
>
> ```
> struct A {
>       int i = /* some integer expression with side effects */ ;
>       A(int arg) : i(arg) { }
>       // ...
> };
> ```
>
> the `A(int)` constructor will simply initialize `i` to the value of `arg`, and the side effects in `i`’s default member initializer will not take place. *—end example*]

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ use g++ which do not produce a warning but the result is the same: `Base` is not initialized with `50` or `23` but with `0`. You can get weirder behavior by adding another attribute before `mymy`:

```
class Derived: public Base {
  public:
  Derived() : Base(mymy), mymymy(mymy), mymy(23) {
      std::cout << "Derived:" << mymy << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Derived:" << mymymy << std::endl;

  }
  int mymymy;
  const int mymy = 50;
};
```

Output from [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22a53c09cf16a8cb):

```
Base:4197208
Derived:23
Derived:4197208
Main:23
```

But if you add an attribute after `mymy`:

```
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
  Derived() : Base(mymy), mymy(23) {
      std::cout << "Derived:" << mymy << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Derived:" << mymymy << std::endl;

  }
  const int mymy = 50;
  int mymymy= mymy;

};
```

The value you provide in the member-initializer-list of the constructor will be used:

```
Base:0
Derived:23
Derived:23
Main:23
```

---

Regarding the `const` qualification: You can always initialize `const` member in the member-list-initializer of your constructor (this is the only place where you can initialize them along with default member initializers).

I don't know if there is a more explicit quote from the standard, but §12.6.2/7<sup>1</sup> (the example is quite explicit though):

> The *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* in a *mem-initializer* is used to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.
>   [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct B1 { B1(int); /* ... */ };
> struct B2 { B2(int); /* ... */ };
> struct D : B1, B2 {
>     D(int);
>     B1 b;
>     const int c;
> };
> D::D(int a) : B2(a+1), B1(a+2), c(a+3), b(a+4)
>     { /* ... */ }
> D d(10);
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Latest C++17 standard draft (N4594).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

If you use ctor initializer then in class initialization is ignored.

Take into account that the call of the base constructor with the argument `mymy`

```
Derived() : Base(mymy), mymy(23) {std::cout << "Derived:" << mymy << std::endl;}
```

is incorrect because the data members of the derived class were not yet initialized.

Comment: Can you please link me to this, in the standard?

Comment: But what about the `const` ? Shouldn't the compiler complain?

Comment: @fritzone Unfortunately I have no access to the Standard now. As for the const qualifier then the ctor also initializes constant data members (except static data members).

Comment: @fritzone In the [last draft of the C++17 standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf) §12.6.2/10: "If a given non-static data member has both a default member initializer and a mem-initializer , the initialization specified by the mem-initializer is performed, and **the non-static data member’s default member initializer is ignored**."